# Java 8 sorting Arraylist of object based on multiple conditions and date

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have a list of object Relationships and inside that there is a object named Contact it will contain either elecType object or postType

```
**Relationships:**
 Relationship:
  date :15/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 1
    usageCode : 1
    elecType(object) :(ecode : 1, detail : ssss )
 Relationship:
  date :14/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 1
    usageCode : 2
    elecType(object) :(ecode : 2, detail :yyy )
 Relationship:
  date :10/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 1
    usageCode : 2
    elecType(object) :(ecode : 2, detail :eee )
 Relationship:
  date :13/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 1
    usageCode : 2
    elecType(object) :(ecode : 1, detail :zzz )
 Relationship:
  date :15/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 1
    usageCode : 1
    elecType(object) :(ecode : 2, detail :ttt )
 Relationship:
  date:12/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 1
    postType(object) : ( detail :xxx )
 Relationship:
  date:11/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 2
    postType(object) : (detail :yyy )
 Relationship:
  date:13/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 2
    postType(object) : (detail :zzz )
```

i need to sort the Relationship,Contacts objects based on the below conditions
if the code is 2, i need to get the latest dated Relationship objects from each Contacts which having  different code
ie :  The will be final output from the above example

```
Relationship:
  date:12/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 1
    postType(object) : (detail :xxx )
  Relationship:
  date:13/10/20
  Contact :
    code : 2
    postType(object) : (detail :zzz )
```

Similarly if the code is 1 , i need to get the latest dated Relationship from each Contacts records which having different usageCode,ecode

ie : from the above data,the output will be

```
    Relationship:
          date :15/10/20
          Contact :
            code : 1
            usageCode : 1
            elecType(object) :(ecode : 1, detail : ssss )
     Relationship:
      date :15/10/20
      Contact :
        code : 1
        usageCode : 1
        elecType(object) :(ecode : 2, detail :ttt )
     Relationship:
          date :13/10/20
          Contact :
            code : 1
            usageCode : 2
            elecType(object) :(ecode : 1, detail :zzz )
     Relationship:
          date :14/10/20
          Contact :
            code : 1
            usageCode : 2
            elecType(object) :(ecode : 2, detail :yyy )
```

### Java Classes

```
    public class Relationship {
      private Date date;
      private Contact contact;
    }
    
    public class Contact{
        private Integer code;
        private Integer usageCode;
        private PostalType postalType;
        private ElecType elecType;
    }

public class PostalType{
  private String detail;

}
public class ElecType{
  private String detail;
  private Integer eCode
}
```

What is the best way to implement this in Java 8 or higher (is it possible to achieve using lambda and streams)

Comment: Use [Java Comparator interface](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework)

Comment: @Holger added the java classes for the question

Comment: That’s a sketch, at best. Not real code.

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement Comparable in your class Relationship and sort a list with

```
Collections.sort(testList);
```

If you want to filter your list, you can use a stream with filter.

```
// filters a List with relationships with code 1
relationships.stream().filter(r -> r.getContacts().getCode() == 1).collect(Collectors.asList());
```